# Looping until background process is done (with `jobs`) doesn't work in script

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting

I'm trying to loop until a background process (launched earlier in the script) is complete. An easily reproducible test case is:

```
ping -c 10 localhost &>/dev/null &
```

On the command line, I can loop `while [[ -n $(jobs) ]]` (while `$(jobs)` is not null).

```
$ ping -c 10 localhost &>/dev/null &
[1] 19078
$ while [[ -n $(jobs) ]]; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done
.........[1]+  Done                    ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null
```

However, the same two lines in a script will keep printing `.`s until I hit `Ctrl-C`.

Weirdly, if I call `jobs` inside the loop, the script ends as expected.

```
$ ./background-ping.sh
.[1]+  Running                 ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null &
.[1]+  Running                 ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null &
.[1]+  Running                 ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null &
.[1]+  Running                 ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null &
.[1]+  Done                    ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null
```

I am aware that there are other ways to check if the background job is complete (e.g. checking `/proc`), but I want to know why checking `jobs` doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem, your 2 lines won't stop in a script.

That's what I made in mine:

```
ping -c 5 google.com &>/dev/null &
while [[ -n $(jobs -r) ]]; do echo -n "."; sleep 1; done
```

`jobs -r` checks running processes, and calling my script works as expected, the script stops when ping is done.

EDIT: I think that in a script the parent process is known as a running process and so that's why `jobs` continue to think that there is a running process. That's an hypothesis

Is that the answer ? (or maybe I really don't understand what you mean, my poor english can be the problem...)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not sure why just `jobs` doesn't work, but this does work.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think that the script is known as a "stopped" process. I checked what's append with `-r` option that only checks running process. It's seems like a bug BTW... maybe you've found a real problem that can be sent to "jobs" author :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have issues like this, you should always try printing your variables so you understand what's going on. In this case, `jobs` also returns finished jobs. If you run this:

```
ping -c 5 localhost &>/dev/null &
while [[ -n $(jobs | tee -a temp) ]]; do
    echo -n .; 
    sleep 1; 
done
```

You will see the following output in `temp`:

```
[1]+  Running                 ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null &
[1]+  Running                 ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null &
[1]+  Running                 ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null &
[1]+  Running                 ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null &
[1]+  Done                    ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null
[1]+  Done                    ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null
[1]+  Done                    ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null
[1]+  Done                    ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null
[1]+  Done                    ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null
[...]
```

So, the output of `jobs` here is never empty. Even when the job is finished, `jobs` still returns the `Done` message. That's why Metal3d's solution using `jobs -r` worked.

What is more confusing is why running `jobs` within the loop causes it to work correctly. The answer will be something to do with the fact that `while [[ -n $(jobs) ]]` runs `jobs` in a separate subshell but I'm not sure about the details. I have [posted a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192170/22222) about this on U&L if anyone is interested.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do by calling `jobs` inside the script. I didn't know about `tee`, though – thanks!

Comment: @stephenwade by the way, my question on U&L has been answered and it is indeed down to subshells. The `jobs` that runs inside the `$()` gets a copy of its parent shell's variables. Those are not changed until you run an extra `jobs` within the loop and that will then update the state which is passed to the next launching of `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wait` command that waits for background jobs to be stopped

Example:

```
$ ping -c 10 localhost &>/dev/null &
[29787]
$ wait
[1]+  Done ping -c 10 localhost &>/dev/null
```

The wait command blocks and when `ping` has finished, prompt is released then prints a message.

You can use is with several commands:

```
$ ping -c 5 localhost &>/dev/null & ping -c 5 facebook.com  &>/dev/null &
[1] 29867
[2] 29868
$ wait
[1]-  Done                    ping -c 5 localhost &>/dev/null
[2]+  Done                    ping -c 5 facebook.com &>/dev/null
```

Comment: As seen in the code examples, I want to print periods to indicate that the process is ongoing, so the `wait` command won't work here.

Comment: "I am aware that there are other ways to check if the background job is complete (e.g. checking `/proc`), but I want to know why checking `jobs` doesn't work as expected."

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, I think I've got solution. Let me try something and I'll tell you